# Shell script time output over java enviroment

Tags: java, timestamps, stat

I am running a script from java program using sshxcute API. Script contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
data=`stat -c%y filename`
echo $data
```

Script running on bash gives output:

```
2014-03-08 13:26:29.335545828 -0800
```

Script running through java program gives output:

```
2014-03-08 21:26:29.335545828 +0000
```

I think the -0800 is getting added. I need output in first format. Anyone have any idea how to resolve the issue?

Comment: It's the time zone difference.

Comment: You posted this on SO earlier, right?

Comment: yes ,but not able to get the desired information

Comment: At that time too, you were told in the comments that it's the time zone.  Moreover, at that time, your question had only the first part.  Refer to help on how to ask a good question.  If you don't provide adequate information in the first instance, chances are that your question wouldn't attract answers.

Comment: How are you running those programs exactly? Post your code. Is the `TZ` environment variable defined at any point (whether it's by your code or not — do `echo $TZ` from the shell script)?